# Jquery-ui Autocomplete and Bootstrap 3 fixed navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to make a autocomplete search using jquery ui and twitter bootstarp. I have added a facny search box to the nav bar and everything seems to be working fine. Please take a look on **code snippet below** or you can also see the same code here on this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aadi1295/d303mnu8/13/), just type 'a' and it will automatically show results in a dropdown list.

Problem is with tablet and mobile version's navbar of bootstrap, for example below code snippet showing tablet version by default, so bootstarp navbar adjust its height, but when I search on tablet or mobile versions, autocomplete results stay behind the navbar which is fixed position. I have tried to fix this issue with z-index and by changing `.ui-autocomplete {position:relative;}`, but nothing is working for me. below is the image of this issue.

[image]

**Please take a look on below code snippet, Thanks**

```js
$(function () {
        // Remove Search if user Resets Form or hits Escape!
  $('body, .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"]').on('click keyup', function(event) {
   console.log(event.currentTarget);
   if (event.which == 27 && $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]').hasClass('active') ||
    $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') == 'reset') {
    closeSearch();
   }
  });

  function closeSearch() {
            var $form = $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active')
      $form.find('input').val('');
   $form.removeClass('active');
  }

  // Show Search if form is not active // event.preventDefault() is important, this prevents the form from submitting
  $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]:not(.active) button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
    $input = $form.find('input');
   $form.addClass('active');
   $input.focus();

  });
    });

$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
  padding: 60px 0px;
 }
 .navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px !important;
  max-height: 270px;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
  background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
  border-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  box-shadow: none;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
  display: none;
 }

 @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
   padding-top: 0px !important;
   padding-right: 38px !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
   width: 38px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
   padding: 15px 12px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
   font-size: 18pt;
   opacity: 0;
   display: none;            
            height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
   width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
   display: table-cell;
   opacity: 1;
  }
     .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
   width: 100%;
  }
 }

.ui-autocomplete {
            z-index:1000;
            max-height: 500px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            position: relative;
            width:500px;
        }
        * html .ui-autocomplete {
            height: 500px;
             z-index:1000;
             width:500px;
        }
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example logo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Drop Down<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please help me fixing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `z-index` of `.ui-autocomplete` to `2000`

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d303mnu8/15/)**

Comment: wow, it's working, Thank so so much. But can I ask a question? why z-index:2000? I had tried z-index:1000 before but does it means somehow navbar have value over 1000?

Comment: @ArbazAbid If you look at the `z-index` of the navbar, it's `1030`.

Comment: I never knew that, I thought they might have not set it that high. It's working fine now. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

You properly need to use `important` keyword. something like:

```
.ui-autocomplete { z-index:2000 !important; }
```